# paplay doesn't play in genmon (Generic Monitor) script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, audio, monitoring

Am I right that paplay doesn't play sounds in genmon (Generic Monitor) script? How to generate sounds in genmon script?

I prepared a script for genmon plugin in my stretch debian xfce

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q --spider http://google.com

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  if [ -e "~./mem" ] ;then
    if grep -q pii "~/mem"; then
      echo "ok">~/mem
      paplay ~/Dropbox/system/ok.ogg
    fi
  else
    echo "pii">~/mem 
  fi
  echo ""
else
  if [ -e "~./mem" ]; then
    if grep -q ok "~/mem"; then
      echo "pii">~/mem
      paplay ~/Dropbox/system/pii.ogg
    fi
  else
    echo "ok">~/mem
  fi
  echo "Offline"
fi
```

This is to signal about internet offline mode. I put such a line to genmon:

`bash -c '~/Dropbox/system/./signal'`

It worked but the sound did not.

When I executed the line in the terminal the sound was played. So how to make sounds play in genmon scripts?

Comment: Not familiar with genmon, but if the script is not called as the users with access to the desktop DBus, `paplay` won't be able to access Pulseaudio, unless Pulseaudio is configured specially.

Comment: Did you try `aplay` instead? Your speakers are turned on, aren't they?

Comment: @dessert aplay is muted too. It plays only when I execute the line `bash -c '~/Dropbox/system/./signal'` in terminal. Not via genmon.